# For the mapping $\varphi: \Bbb{Z}+\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$ given by $(a,b) \to a-b$, describe the set $\varphi^{-1} (3).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here's what I got so far:

By the properties of group homomorphisms, we know that if $\varphi(a,b) = 3$, then $\varphi^{-1} (3) = (a,b) + \ker(\varphi)$. For this given homomorphism, the kernel is the set of elements $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}+\Bbb{Z}$ such that $a=b$, hence $(a,a)$ for $a \in \Bbb{Z}$.

So, $\varphi^{-1} (3) = (a,b) + (a,a)$. Also, since the homomorphism is defined as $\varphi(a,b) = a-b$, we know that $3 = a-b$. Taking $a = b + 3$,

\begin{align*}(a,b) + (a,a) &= (b+3,b) + (b+3,b+3) \\ &= (b+3+b+3, b+b+3) \\ &= (2b + 6, 2b + 3).\end{align*}

By the defined homomorphism, I got $2b+6-(2b+3) = 3$. But this is not it since I'm suppose to get a set to define $\varphi^{-1} (3)$.

The answer in the book is this: $\varphi^{-1} (3) = \{(a+3,a) | a \in \Bbb{Z}\}$. Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong with my steps? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We have $\varphi^{-1}(3)$ consists of all pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a-b=3$. One can put this in various ways, they are the integer points on a certain simple line. The homomorphism stuff is I think confusing you.

Comment: Yes, it is a homomorphism of Abelian groups.

Answer (score 1):

You denote different things with same letters. Anyway, you're absolutely right.

1. After you successfully found the kernel of $\phi$, you can find an arbitrary preimage of $3$, say $(3,0)$, and then state that
   $$\phi^{-1}(3)=(3,0)+\ker\phi\,.$$
2. Alternatively, you can directly conclude, without referring to the kernel: by definition
   $$\phi^{-1}(3)=\{(a,b)\,\mid\,a-b=3\}=\{(b+3,b)\,\mid\,b\in\Bbb Z\}$$

You have done both and used the same letters. (It is also a correct answer if you write $\{(b+3,b)+(x,x)\,\mid\, b,x\in\Bbb Z\}$.)